# How to read/processes 100 lines at a time from 10000 lines in python?

Tags: python

How to pass/processes  100 lines or lower to `try:` at a time ?

```
receipt_dict = {}
with open("data.txt", "r") as plain_text: // ** 10000+ lines **
    for line in plain_text:
        hash_value = line.strip()
        receipt_dict[hash_value] = 1



try:
    bitcoind.sendmany("", receipt_dict) // **here must loop 100 at a time**
```

Comment: with threads ? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: What is the format of the lines?

Comment: The lines are plain text in the data.txt, then i add '1' so final is a python dictionary  : { 'line': 1,...} 
                 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With generators. Here, `load_data_chunks` accumulates data in `receipt_dict` until its size exceeds `chunk_size` and yields it back to main loop below.

```
def load_data_chunks(path, fname, chunk_size): 
    receipt_dict = {}

    with open(fname, "r") as plain_text:
        for line in plain_text:
            hash_value = line.strip()
            receipt_dict[hash_value] = 1

            if len(receipt_dict) > chunk_size:
                yield receipt_dict
                receipt_dict = {}

    yield receipt_dict

for chunk in load_data_chunks("data.txt", 100):
    try:
        ...
```

Comment: Very good code! thanks, i had to change 100 to 99, i think it counts the 0

Answer (score 1):

Process it as a `list` of dictionaries, keeping track of the size of each dictionary:

```
receipt_dicts = []
current_dict = {}
with open("data.txt", "r") as plain_text: # ** 10000+ lines **
    for line in plain_text:
        if len(current_dict) == 100:
            receipt_dict.append(current_dict)
            current_dict = {}
        current_dict[line.strip()] = 1
    receipt_dict.append(current_dict)
```

You can then loop through this `list` and process one dictionary at a time.